# Dynamically populating choicefield in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I can't initialize the `Choicefield` form inside the `views.py`. I tried passing the `option` variable in the `__init__` function but I got an error:

```
__init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` coming from the `form = super(SomeeWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
        def __init__(self, choice, *args, **kwargs):
            super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['choices'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[ (o.id, str(o)) for o in choice])
```

**views.py**

```
class SomeWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(SomeWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        if step == "step2":
            option = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step("step1")['choice']

            choice = Choice.objects.filter(question__text__exact=option)

            form = SomeForm(choice)

        return form

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html')
```

**EDIT**

I tried Hasan solution and Django Form Wizard is passing `{'files': None, 'prefix': 'step2', 'initial': {}, 'data': None}` into the `**kwarg` in the `__init__` function of `SomeForm`.

I printed the content in the `**kwarg` and I got:

`{'files': None, 'prefix': 'step2', 'initial': {}, 'data': None}
{'choices': [<Choice: Blue>, <Choice: Red>]}`

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

try this change(I comment changed line):

`forms.py`:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): #this line changed
        choice = kwargs.pop('choice', None) #this line added
        self.fields['choices'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[ (o.id, str(o)) for o in choice])
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`views.py`:

```
class SomeWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(SomeWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        if step == "step2":
            option = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step("step1")['choice']

            choice = Choice.objects.filter(question__text__exact=option)

            form = SomeForm(choice=choice) #this line changed

        return form

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kargs):
        return render_to_response('done.html')
```

Comment: I got `'NoneType' object is not iterable` then I tried removing `None` in `choice = kwargs.pop('choice', None)` and got the `KeyError` with `choice`.

Comment: this error occured because `choice = Choice.objects.filter(question__text__exact=option)` return `None`.

Comment: With the KeyError, it has to do with Django form wizard passing in `{'files': None, 'prefix': 'step2', 'initial': {}, 'data': None}` in the `kwarg`. I can't seem to figure out how stop that.

Comment: check your `option` variable. and alse check there are `Choice` object with `uestion__text__exact=option` filter?

Comment: Checked `option` and `Choice` variable and they seem fine.

Comment: Nevermind I actually got it. Thanks for the help though Hasan.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had to init the form with the data attribute for this to work. For example:

```
class SomeWizard(SessionWizardView):

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(SomeWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)

        # determine the step if not given
        if step is None:
            step = self.steps.current

        if step == "2":
            option = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step("1")['choice']

            choice = Choice.objects.filter(question__text__exact=option)


            ## Pass the data when initing the form, which is the POST
            ## data if the got_form function called during a post
            ## or the self.storage.get_step_data(form_key) if the form wizard
            ## is validating this form again in the render_done methodform 
            form = SomeForm(choice=choice, data=data) 

        return form

def get_template_names(self):
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

def done(self, form_list, **kargs):
    return render_to_response('done.html')
```

Otherwise when the form was submitted it just returned my back to this first form. For a full explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740361/django-formwizard-with-dynamic-form-does-not-proceed-to-next-step?noredirect=1#comment53321789_32740361). I am using django 1.8 though.